# Help in finding the simplified formula of a tiered fare

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Please help me find the simplest formula in getting the fare. I can get the fare using layman's calculation (i don't know if that is the correct term) but what I need is a formula. I'm stuck with what I did and I thought that this is the best place to get help. I think it's best to explain this is through example. So,

```
Problem: Find fare of passenger who will travel a total distance of 12km.

Tiered Fare Matrix:

                        | TIER 0 | TIER 1 | TIER 2 | TIER 3 | TIER n
incremental distance (m)| 1000   | 3000   | 3000   | 3000   | dn
              rate ($/m)| 0.2    | 3      | 2.5    | 2      | rn
```

where,

TIER 0 is the lowest tier or the starting point

$m$ = meters

$r$ = rate

$d$ = distance

dn = ${d_n}$  = nth distance

rn = $r_n$ = nth rate

Comment: The above data does not make sense - for example, is the distance (m) the total distance? or is it is the incremental distance i.e. you have 0.2 for the first 1000m, then it is 3 for 1000m to 4000m etc? 

Then the rates suggest that you charge more for the tier 1 than tier 2 which is ok, if tier 0 is the highest.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained it clearly. distance (m) is the incremental distance and tier 0 is the lowest tier or the the starting point.

Comment: You basically have $1000 \times 0.2 + 3000 \times 3 + 3000 \times 2.5 + 3000 \times 2 + \cdots + d_n r_n$. Next time you should show your own work and see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).